# A chain 64 meters long whose mass is 20 kilograms is hanging over the edge of a tall building...

Tags: calculus

A chain 64 meters long whose mass is 20 kilograms is hanging over the edge of a tall building and does not touch the ground. How much work is required to lift the top 3 meters of the chain to the top of the building? Use that the acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 meters per second squared. Your answer must include the correct units.

Comment: More appropriate for physics.SE? Anyway a simple difference of potential should give the answer.

Comment: This is a common sort of problem in a calculus course on integral applications, so it doesn't seem out of place to me.

Comment: The below answer is NOT right. Can anyone else help me?

Comment: Is all the 64 meters hanging over? It makes no sense how it is worded. If you list the top 3 meters you are just lifting the end of the chain. Also, are you pulling the entire chain up or just the end up? (they are different problems)

Comment: If the chain is uniform (mass is uniformly distributed), and is at rest at the beginning and the end of the operation, and there is no friction, then a simple computation of the potential energy before and after will do the trick, not forgetting the 3m at the top of the tower at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ denote the position along the chain in meters, with $x=0$ corresponding to the top of the chain at the top of the building. Let $\delta x$ denote a small length of chain. To figure out the total work, we break up the chain into small pieces of equal length $\delta x,$ compute the work to move each piece, and add it all together.

The top piece does not need to be lifted further. A piece at approximately $x$ meters down the chain needs to move $x$ meters if $x\le 3,$ or simply moves $3$ meters if $x\ge 3.$

The work required to lift a piece is $xF$ if $x\le 3,$ or $3F$ otherwise, where $F$ is the force due to gravity. Assuming the chain has constant density, the force acting on a small $\delta x$ of chain is $F=mg=(\frac{20}{64}\delta x)(9.8) = 3.0625 \delta x.$

So to move a small $\delta x$-length of chain takes $3.0625x\delta x$ Joules of work if $0\le x\le 3.$ Summing up the work over these small lengths corresponds to integrating $\int_0^3 3.0625xdx.$

The work required to move the rest of the chain is easier, since all the remaining $\delta x$-lengths move the same distance: $3$ meters. So we can compte this all at once as $3F=3mg=3(\frac{20}{64}61)(9.8)=560.4375$ Joules of work.

Comment: Andrew, your answer is not right. I checked it with the online WebWork my homework is in.

Comment: I haven't computed the final answer yet, I left that for you to do.

Comment: Ryan: Simple correction would suggest to include in your question the indications and/or full answer you received from the online WebWork.